# redux-saga function not being called after the action is dispatched from the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

i am trying to render my cart collection from my mongodb into my cart component, for that i have created a  GET api which is working fine (checked through postman) but when i am dispatching the action i have created to call the redux-saga function, the action function is being called but the redux-saga function is not being called.

//cartAction.js

```
import { CART_LIST } from "./constant";

// action for cartSaga to fetch cart list API.
export const cartList = () => {
    console.log('cartList action is called');
    return {
     type: CART_LIST,
     payload: 'data'
     
    } 
};
```

//cartSaga.js

```
import { takeEvery, put } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { CART_LIST, SET_CART_LIST } from "./constant";


function* getCartItems() {
    let cartList = yield fetch('http://localhost:7000/cart/');
    cartList = yield cartList.json();
    console.log("data from cartSaga", cartList);
    yield put({ type: SET_CART_LIST, data: cartList})
}

function* cartSaga() {
    yield takeEvery(CART_LIST, getCartItems)
} 
export default cartSaga;
```

the console.log in cartAction.js is running but cartSaga.js function cartSaga is not.  i have checked it from my end but can not find the issue, Kindly help.

i have checked the type in my cartAction.js, it is the same as in my cartSaga.js function cartSaga, i.e CART_LIST. i have also checked the imports but could not find anything wrong.

Comment: DO you have any parent wrapper file to combine all the saga files did you register your saga file to that?

Comment: no, i have created a different reducer file for my cartSaga.js file and connected that reducer to the rootReducer

Comment: You must have rootSaga file as well. and that root saga file has to be defined in the store middleware.

Comment: Thank you @AshishPatel, after creating rootSaga file, now it's working.